# Parametrized composed annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, annotations

### Use case

Some of my entities have a `Money` field, i.e. a single class field that is backed by two DB columns. This is achieved by following Hibernate annotation:

```
@Columns(
    columns = [
        Column(name = "amount_currency", length = 3, nullable = false),
        Column(name = "amount", nullable = false),
    ],
)
var amount: Money
```

The annotation is visually complicated and in fact is almost the same for all `Money` fields in my entities - except for the column names.

### Question

Is it somehow possible to deduplicate this common pattern? My idea would be to create a composed annotation which I would then use like

```
@MoneyColumns(baseName="amount")
var amount: Money
```

The problem is I totally don't know how to define such annotation. My original way of thinking was to use composed annotations with delegation ala Spring's `@AliasFor` but that seems to target only simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible out of the box. If you have a naming scheme, you should maybe look into `ImplicitNamingStrategy` where you should be able to access annotations of your model elements (with some casting and resolving) and generate the proper implicit names. If you also want to reuse the column length config, you'd probably have to model this as `@Embeddable` which you can easily reuse.

Comment: I tried the `@Embeddable` approach but it looks only marginally better, i.e. at the use site:
```
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name = "amount", column = Column(name = "amount"))
    @AttributeOverride(name = "currency", column = Column(name = "amount_currency"))
    var amount: MoneyEmbeddable,
```
Moreover, it requires some additional steps because I eventually need the `org.javamoney.moneta.Money` type. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: There is no better way yet. There is a Hibernate feature request for an embeddable prefix though, so you might want to vote on that or even try implementing this by yourself in Hibernate.